# Module object not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
File "C:/Python36/Projects/NFL/read in.py", line 8, in <module>
    table = bs(open('C:\page.html','r').read()).find('table')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Receiving the above error when i try to load a save .html page back into a script with `bs4`. It happens whether the file is in or out of the scripts folder so i moved it to the c drive for ease.

```
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import os


table = bs(open('C:\page.html','r').read()).find('table')
dfs = pd.read_html(table)

for df in dfs:
    print(dfs)

    df.to_csv('ALL_Ref_AtBats.csv', mode='a')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to import [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using escape sequences in the file path string...

You defined the file path as `'C:\page.html'`. Here, `\p` after `C:` has a special meaning just as `\n` means a newline (not merely a `\n`).

You could fix this by providing the file path as `'C:\\page.html'` or `r'C:\page.html'` or `'C:/page.html'`.

**Tip:** `r'...'` returns a string without any escape sequence.